# cant get cassete to work on .net framework 4

Tags: asp.net, bundle, cassette

I added Cassete via NuGet and i got the Views/web.config file and I followed the steps on documentation:

Create a bundle in CassetteConfigurtaion.cs:

```
 public void Configure(BundleCollection bundles, CassetteSettings settings)
    {

        settings.IsDebuggingEnabled = true;

        bundles.Add<ScriptBundle>("jquery","js/jquery/jquery.js");
    }
```

Call Bundles.References in my .aspx page

```
<% 
     Bundles.Reference("jquery", "header");
%>
```

While doing some testing i got errors like "/bundlePath/bundle is already created" so i guess the bundle is getting created but i just cant make it to load the files once i run the application

Answer (score 0):

The problem that i had was that i was missing a "=" sign when I called the RenderScripts() method, i have to put it like this:

```
<%= Bundles.RenderScripts() %>
```

And thats it, that was the problem.